# C: do bit flags have a priority order?

Tags: c, bit, sdl-2, flags

I was reading SDL2 documentation, in particular [SDL_CreateWindow](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindow) function and the possible flags for its `flags` argument: [SDL_WindowFlags](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WindowFlags).

Since there are flags that are "mutually exclusive", for example `SDL_WINDOW_MINIMIZED`(64) and `SDL_WINDOW_MAXIMIZED`(128) I assume that one must be applied before the other or one gets ignored.
Therefore, if we set both of them as follows:

```c
SDL_CreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_MINIMIZED | SDL_WINDOW_MAXIMIZED);
```

the result is that the window gets **minimized** when the application starts.

So my question is: **is there some kind of order priority rule**?

I apologize if that's a duplicate, but couldn't formulate the question well enough to find the answer anywhere else.

Comment: That will depend on the code your calling to resolve.

Comment: @Taekahn The question is specifically about the SDL API.

Comment: Probably implementation-defined and you'd have to look at the SDL source code. Not sure this is the actual code [here](https://github.com/zielmicha/SDL2/blob/master/src/video/SDL_video.c#L1153) but this code will maximize and then immediately minimize the window.

Comment: @jarmod exactly, I could have thought before to go look the actual source code since it's open source... however it's precisely at [SDL_video.c line 1160](https://github.com/zielmicha/SDL2/blob/master/src/video/SDL_video.c#L1160). Thank you all

Comment: @Barmar I disagree. that’s the context. The question is quite explicitly general in both the title and at the end where is says “so my question is:” and lays out the entirety of the question.

Comment: The title is general, the question is clearly (IMHO) asking about SDL-2. It's also in the tags.

Comment: If the interface documentation says that two flags are mutually exclusive, then do not set both of them. You're violating the contract by doing so.

Comment: @Barmar  I was wondering if there was a general convention or something, with specific attention on the SDL2 example, but it's my bad I should have formulated the question properly, this way it was a bit misleading

Comment: @Kaz you're right but the documentation doesn't specify anything about it (see the links of the question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bit flags in C don't have a priority order. A bit flag is perfectly happy to have the bits 128 and 64 at the same time. The compiler doesn't even know that 128 means maximized and 64 means minimized!

The `SDL_CreateWindow` function, however, will have its own priority order according to the creators of SDL. The relevant source code can be found [here](https://github.com/zielmicha/SDL2/blob/master/src/video/SDL_video.c#L1160):

> ```
>     if (flags & SDL_WINDOW_MAXIMIZED) {
>         SDL_MaximizeWindow(window);
>     }
>     if (flags & SDL_WINDOW_MINIMIZED) {
>         SDL_MinimizeWindow(window);
>     }
> ```

so if you use both the maximized flag and also the minimized flag, *SDL* (not C) will maximize and then minimize the window, so it ends up minimized.

Comment: I was also wondering if there was like a general preference, for example following the bits order (from most to least significant bit or viceversa), but at this point I think there isn't. Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: There is no general preferance, sometimes you will encounter functions that do as this one and one bit "wins" but other times the code will simply bail and give some kind of invalid arguments error.